# Angular 10 | how to user multiple router params in routerLink

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use my route params in routerLink html
but the problem is that the routes have only params like that

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':user',
    component: UserComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':page',
    component: PageComponent
  }
];
```

So, when I use routerLink for `PageComponent` in html like this

```
<a [routerLink]="[data]">John</a>
```

it always go to the first route `UserComponent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have both ':user' and ':page' because you are telling angular that exists two routes like this "/yourparam" and of course angular does not know how to handle them and therefore always gives you the first.

You could do like this :

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'user/:user',
    component: UserComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'page/:page',
    component: PageComponent
  }
];
```

If you want you can also setup children routes.